# Aborting from inside a ScheduledTask

Tags: evaluation

If you have an `Abort[]` inside a `ScheduledTask` expression, what does it abort? The scheduled task evaluation, or any main kernel evaluation that is ongoing?

Comment: have you tried it?

Comment: Yes, and I know the answer. I'm contributing this question which came to me from a Mathematica user because (a) it's not necessarily obvious what it should do and (b) it's not currently documented.

Comment: My guess/expectation is that it would only abort whatever is being evaluated in the task. What is the answer?

Comment: I tried and it only aborts the task.  An explanation would be nice since you know the internals :-)  How does this functionality even work?  Does it depend on anything outside of the kernel (e.g. Java)?  Are these pre-emptive evaluations (like `Button` by default)?  Is the functionality exactly the same as ``Internal`Periodicals`` or different?

Comment: It is strongly recommended to self answer, the more that your answer would be the most reliable here :)

Comment: I experimented a bit, and it seems that the evaluations done by scheduled tasks are just like pre-emptive evaluations.  `PreemptProtect` affects them and in general `Abort[]` in pre-emptive evaluations does not seem to affect the ongoing main evaluation, even though the `Stack[]` is shared between them.  Joel, I think it's time you posted your own answer.  Most likely no one else is going to do it, since we can just guess at the details.

Answer (score 9):

`Abort[]` inside a scheduled task will abort the rest of the task expression at the given time, not any main evaluation. It will also repeat to evaluate the task (up till the `Abort[]`) if further time slots are scheduled.

To show this, first start a scheduled task:

```
RunScheduledTask[
 Print[DateString[], " Scheduled task before Abort[]"]; Abort[]; 
 Print[DateString[], " Scheduled task after Abort[]"], {5, 3}, 5]
```

By itself you can see that the scheduled task expression gets aborted: in the Messages window you will see the "before" Print output, but not the "after".

While this is running, start a long-running evaluation in a cell:

```
Print["Mersenne primes:"]; 
Do[
   With[{n = 2^i - 1, i = i}, 
      If[PrimeQ[n], Print[HoldForm[2^i - 1 == n]]]
   ], 
   {i, 10^6}
]
```

This keeps evaluating even when the scheduled task issues its `Abort`.

Comment: I have included some clarification, hope you don't mind!

Comment: That's great, thank you!

Comment: @JoelKlein After starting the long-running evaluation I do not see messages from the `ScheduledTask` no more (I use v. 8.0.4). Why this happens?