# Why can't I abort main evaluation from ScheduledTasks (Service Link)?

Tags: front-end, evaluation, kernel, windows, scheduling

`FrontEndExecute[FrontEndToken["EvaluatorAbort"]]` is equivalent of the menu item: `Evaluation >> Abort`.

It works with signals as explained in [Difference between Evaluation>>Quit Kernel and Quit[]](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/67096/5478).

One can use it, from *preemptive link*, to abort e.g. a loop:

```
Button["Abort", FrontEndExecute[FrontEndToken["EvaluatorAbort"]], 
       Method -> "Preemptive"]
While @ True
```

> ```
> $Aborted (*after click*)
> ```

#### Question: I can't do this from `ScheduledTasks`, why?

I was expecting here that after first `Print` the loop will be broken (*you would see cell bracket stop being highlighted, but it is still bold*)

```
RunScheduledTask[
 Print[DateString[]];
 FrontEndExecute[FrontEndToken["EvaluatorAbort"]];
 ,
 {1, 3}, 5]
While @ True
```

---

#### Few notes:

`ScheduledTasks` are returned by *Service Link*:

> [image]

but I don't know why this matters.

#### Related topics:

[Aborting from inside a ScheduledTask](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/38374/5478)

[Installing LinkSnooper on Windows](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/66070/5478)

[What are the purposes of functions in FrontEnd` context](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/67179/5478)

---

[cross posted on Wolfram Community](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/449896?p_p_auth=zS1u30rD)

Comment: It's a bit late here, but from the top of my head I know only one reason for that: the kernel simply ignores this signal when it comes over the service link. Why the kernel does it? I have no clue at the moment.

Comment: Btw, *over the service link* was written badly, because it is a signal, but it seems it has something to do that it is evaluated in the scheduled task.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pulling the Linksnooper out of your pocket was the right call and I guess you would have found this yourself soon. Please don't ask me about the *why*, because I don't know it. Additionally, I have only tested this on Linux.

Let's create a small test using the `"EvaluatorAbort"` FE token

```
Button["Abort", FrontEndExecute[FrontEndToken["EvaluatorAbort"]]]
```

You need to know two things: This command is send to the kernel for evaluation. The kernel sees the `FrontEndExecute` and sends the FE token back to the FE. The FE is now expected to send the Kernel a signal to abort. How the last part works is kind of explained [in the answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/67770/187) you already referred to.

The big question is, will the FE always send signal 3 if I hit the button. Unfortunately, this seems not to be the case, because when I press it without any computation running the LinkSnooper shows only

[image]

When I run a `While[True]` before pressing the button on the other hand, I see the following

[image]

It seems that the FE has the final word in whether or not it likes to do what I asked it to do. Now, it seems that when you use `RunScheduledTask`, the FE ignores this all the time, even if a evaluation is running. There is not much I can do about this.

On the other hand, we do know that all communication is done through *MathLink* or as we're ordered to call it these days *Wolfram Symbolic Transfer Protocol* aka WSTP. Therefore, I tried to circumvent the `FrontEndExecute` by writing the token directly to the FE link.

At least on my machine, this was successful and the loop is aborted:

```
RunScheduledTask[Print[DateString[]];
 LinkWrite[First[$FrontEnd], FrontEndToken["EvaluatorAbort"]];, {1, 3}, 5]
While@True
```